# Laravel how to add group prefix parameter to route function

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

For example, I have defined routes like this:

```
$locale = Request::segment(1);

Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function()
{
  Route::get('/about', ['as' => 'about', 'uses' => 'aboutController@index']);
}
```

I want to generate links for several locales (en, de, es,...). When I try to provide prefix parameter like this

```
$link = route('about',['prefix' => 'de']);
```

I got link like this `example.com/en/about?prefix=de` 
How to provide prefix param to got link like this `example.com/de/about`

Comment: I don't think laravel route has any function for that. Checkout this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers)

Comment: Yes there is check [**docs**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)

Comment: Yes, @Uchiha it could be possible with named parameter in property prefix for that group. Thanks

Comment: @KalanjDjordjeDjordje #sixFingersMan answer is correct

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can play around with something like this perhaps.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function () {
    Route::get('about', ['as' => 'about', 'uses' => '....']);
});

route('about', 'en');  // http://yoursite/en/about
route('about', 'de');  // http://yoursite/de/about
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$locale = Request::segment(1);

Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function()
{
    Route::get('/about', ['as' => 'about', 'uses' => 'aboutController@index']);
}
```

And while providing a link, you can use url helper function instead of route:

```
$link = url('de/about');
```

If you want more generic, use this in controller/view:

```
 $link = url($locale.'/about');
```

where $locale could be `en,de,etc`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'de'],function(){
    Route::get('/about', [
       'as' => 'about',
       'uses' => 'aboutController@index'
    ]);

});
```

Now `route('about')` will give link like this :  `example.com/de/about`

Comment: I don't need to define route. I need to get url for route with other prefix.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **prefix** method within a **Route group** to define a common prefix for a group of routes.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    // Your admin routes here
    Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard');
    Route::get('users', 'AdminController@users');
    // ...
});
```

In the above example, all routes defined within the **Route::group** will have the **"/admin"** prefix.

Official Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-groups

Answer (score -1):

You can simply achieve it like as

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'de'], function () {
    Route::get('about', ['as' => 'de.about', 'uses' => 'aboutController@index']);
});
```

And you can use it like as

```
$link = route('de.about');
```

Comment: `de` is not necessary in child routes

Comment: sorry, I little improved a question. Problem is how to generically change prefix while call route function

Comment: But its easy to identify @BasheerAhmed

Comment: @BasheerAhmed It won't